# How do you fix missing partition on OS X El Cap?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, macos, partition

After trying to install Windows 10 via Boot Camp, my Mac automatically rebooted (supposedly to the newly created Windows partition). However, it just booted back my OS X 10.11.2.

When I went to Boot Camp Assistant, it's as if the installation never happened. The partition was taken, but OS X can't read the missing partition:
[image: Disk Utility not seeing the partition]

Here's the output of sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  488555536      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  488965176    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  490234712          7         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

How do I recover this missing partition/disk space?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` entered in Terminal to your question. Did you try to revert to the previous state with Boot Camp Assistant ("...remove Windows...")?

Comment: @klanomath When I opened Boot Camp Assistant to try to revert, it's acting as if there's nothing to revert

Answer (score 1):

The GUID partition table looks good. Nothing is really missing. The partition with the index number 2 is a CoreStorage Logical Volume Group. The partition with the index number 3 is your Recovery HD. The Boot Camp Assistant probably failed to resize the LVG (~ 250 GB) but succeeded resizing the Logical Volume (*Macintosh HD* ~ 192 GB). As a result about 58 GB in the CoreStorage LVG are not allocated to Logical Volumes.

To expand *Macintosh HD* boot to your Recovery HD (hold <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting). Open *Disk Utility* and verify the integrity of the superior CoreStorage LVG and the inferior LV (Macintosh HD). Then open Terminal in the menubar Utilities -> Terminal

- Enter `diskutil cs list`.
- Enter `diskutil cs resizeVolume lvUUID size`. *lvUUID* is the UUID of the Logical Volume; usually it's the last listed in the output of `diskutil cs list`. Use 250g as size. If you get an error (not enough space...) use a slightly smaller size like 249500m.
- Enter `exit`, quit Terminal and reboot to your main volume.

Comment: When I ran [code]diskutil resizeStack lvUUID size[/code], I got the error:

"diskutil did not recognize verb resizeStack"

Perhaps, another command?

Comment: seems to be the right command. But I got this new error message:

"Error: -69674: The provided Core Storage logical volume has an incorrect size; you should run whole-disk repair"

Full screenshot here: https://goo.gl/photos/mnPtVy7NAAeyMvXm7

Comment: @AllanCaeg Do you have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: making one. Do you recommend simply wiping then recovering via Time Machine?

Comment: @AllanCaeg I recommend backing up the entire volume, then detach the backup drive. Now you can try to revert the CoreStorage LVG to a normal partition. If successful expand the classical (non-FileVault) volume and re-encrypt it later. If not successful restore the backup.